# Searching string from every position with regex so it finds overlapping matches

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex doesn't find overlapping matches, is there a way to do find them?

Example regex that illustrates the problem: `/(\d\*x\^(\d))\+(\d\*x\^(\d))/g`

String to perform this regex on: `3*x^2+2*x^3+6*x^2`

Matches: `3*x^2+2*x^3`

Desired matches: `3*x^2+2*x^3`, `2*x^3+6*x^2`

I want to use this in a replace function, and check if the first digit is greater than the second, if that is the case, it should switch them around. Because it doesn't match overlapping matches, it doesn't work.

I checked another answer about this, but don't know how to implement it with the replace function in JavaScript.

I've got this so far:

```
var string1 = "3*x^2+2*x^3+6*x^2";
var newString1 = string1.replace(/(\d\*x\^(\d))\+(\d\*x\^(\d))/g, function (piece, $1, $2, $3, $4) {
    if ($2 > $4) {
        return $3 + "+" + $1;
    } else {
        return piece;
    }
});
```

Or, if you know a better tool to solve this problem instead of regexp, like mentioned in the comments, please provide a solution using that tool.

Comment: can't you just split by `'+'`, sort and then join again by `'+'`? `"3+5+4+6+7".split('+').sort((a, b) => Number(a) - Number(b) ).join('+')`

Comment: I might, but "3+5+4+6+7" was just an example, strings I actually have to deal with are of formats like `3*x^2 + 2*x^3 + 6*x^2`, and what I want to do is order all the pieces without spaces based on their exponent. Could I do that with split? (The outcome for this example should then be `3*x^2 + 6*x^2 + 2*x^3`)

Comment: I did state in the question that I wanted  a way to find overlapping matches, and to use that to solve my problem, but I'll put this in the question as well.

Comment: Regexp is probably not the best tool to use for this. Write a real parser and expression evaluator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below just uses split, reverse, join.
It orders the pieces between the '+' based on the reversed pieces.
Thus sorts them by the exponent.

For example `3*x^2+2*x^3+6*x^2` becomes `3*x^2+6*x^2+2*x^3`

```js
var str = "3*x^2+2*x^3+6*x^2";

var result = str
      .split('').reverse().join('')  // reverse the string
      .split('+')                    // split into an array by the +
      .sort().reverse()              // sort the array descending
      .join('+')                     // join the array by + to a string
      .split('').reverse().join(''); // reverse the string
      
console.log(result);
```

As for how to use regex to get each piece and the piece after this?
That can be done via a positive lookahead that has a capture group in it.

```js
var str = "3*x^2+2*x^3+6*x^2";
var re = /(\d\*x\^(\d))(?=\+?(\d\*x\^(\d))?)/g;
var m;
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[1], "exponent:"+m[2], m[3], "exponent:"+m[4]);
}
```